# In which chapter of Mahabharatha, the narrator did not enumerate all names due to complexity?

Tags: scripture, mahabharata, name

In many scriptures, if there is a large list of names, the authors or narrators generally do not take the burden of enumerating all the names due to the complexity i.e., the size of the list.

While reading a chapter in Mahabharatha, I noticed that the narrator (probably Vaisampanya) explicitly tells that he will not enumerate all the names explicitly as the list is large. Although I remember such a saying, I did not remember the specific chapter number or parva.

In which chapter of the Mahabharatha, the narrator explicitly says that he is not going to enumerate all the names due to complexity?

*Note*: The motivation for asking the question is to get references on scriptures opting to avoid the names of big lists even if the author or narrator has the knowledge of the total list of names.